# Qual diferença entre >>= e >>>= em Java?

Tags: java, operadores

Lendo um livro sobre a linguagem Java, deparei com alguns operadores que até então nunca tinha observado. Eles são: `>>`, `<<`, `>>=`, `<<=`, `>>>`, `<<<`, `>>>=` e `<<<=`. Suponho eu que sabendo a diferença entre apenas duas dessas operações sendo `>>=` e `>>>=`, é possível que esclareça sobre todas as outras.

Qual diferença entre `>>=` e `>>>=`? Em qual situação podem ser aplicadas?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Isso não tem nada de OOP. Estes são operadores de bits, no caso são os operadores compostos de atribuição, então ele pegará esta variável aplicará o operador e o resultado será guardado na própria variável. Pode dizer que ele faz a operação *inplace*.

O `>>=` desloca os bits para a direita e vai preenchendo com 0 os da esquerda que vão ficando "vazios". Já o `>>>=` faz o mesmo mas desconsiderando o sinal.

```
class HelloWorld {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        int x = -100;
        x >>= 2;
        System.out.println(x);
        x = 100;
        x >>= 2;
        System.out.println(x);
        x = -100;
        x >>>= 2;
        System.out.println(x);
        x = 100;
        x >>>= 2;
        System.out.println(x);
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](http://ideone.com/NezA7x). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/jjbgrsby-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/bigown/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Math/BitShift.java).

Comment: Legal, com essa edição esclareceu melhor! Obrigado.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento é, fiz correndo, obrigado.